# ESLINT_ERROR || Parsing error: Unexpected token createCarRecord : Source

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Unable to save the controller file in Lightning when i try to add below line to my code.

```
Var createCarRecord = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
```

Full code after adding above line is

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        //will fetch from backend
        Var createCarRecord = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        /*if(createCarRecord){
            component.set("component.showNew",true);
        }else{
            component.set("component.showNew",false);
        }*/

        component.set("v.carTypes",['Sports Car','Luxury Car','Van']);
        var cartype = component.get("v.carTypes")
    }
  })
```

when i try to save i'm getting the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of `Var`. It should be `var`. Its case sensitive.

Comment: Thank You so much..